# IBM DB2 solution for GIT

Tags: git, db2, synchronization, solution

How Can we create a solution for IBM DB2 entities and how can we sync them with GIT .

I have DB2 Database, frequently I will make some changes to entities, I need to maintain versioning for all these entities in GIT and also, If i want to Deploy any changes into to DB, I should be able to create a differential script. So that I can execute them directly in DB instead of Dropping the existing ones and recreate...

Comment: Any inputs will be appreciated

Comment: Entirely unclear what you are asking

Comment: I have DB2 Database, frequently I will make some changes to entities, I need to maintain versioning for all these entities in GIT and also, If i want to Deploy any changes into to DB, I should be able to create a differential script. So that I can execute them directly in DB instead of Dropping  the existing ones and recreate...

Comment: Edit your question and add those and more details.

Comment: Ok, now as a next step, show what you already have, your research and code that is not working.

Comment: https://www.liquibase.org/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using IBM Data Studio. This is an Eclipse based tool and includes the eclipse Git plug-in. It can generate "change plans" https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS62YD_4.1.0/com.ibm.datatools.uom.ui.doc/topics/c_changeplans.html

Other third party tools are also available